# How to convert Object to Map using object mapper in spring webflux in a non-blocking way

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a situation where i have to create a JWT token and return it. But my JWT token function required claims as a Map object. So in spring MVC i was doing it like this

`objectMapper.convertValue(userDetails, Map.class);`

But I am afraid of using this as it is in my webflux application because it looks like blocking operation.

Can i use objectmapper`s convertValue function as it is or i have to do something else.

Comment: why does it look like a blocking operation? have you tried it?

Comment: yes i tried it but i would like to confirm that we use same methods in non-blocking

Comment: if you are afraid of blocking operation i recommend you start using BlockHound to detect blocking operations https://github.com/reactor/BlockHound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`objectMapper.convertValue(userDetails, Map.class)` is a synchronous operation, but it does not perform any blocking operations (e.g. blocking I/O).

Therefore it is safe to call in a WebFlux app without worrying about blocking an I/O event loop or the parallel Scheduler.